# Hovering to affect elements higher in the parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have an issue when hovering, I'd like it to be that when I hover on either the image or the button, the button has opacity and the image scales in its container.

I can achieve all of the above using a combination of .css, (:hovers) and using the (+) going down inside the parent element.

HOWEVER when I hover on the circular button, I can't get the .css to also select the image above, as there doesn't seem to be a sudo selector to go up inside the parent element.

So I tried adding a simple bit of Jquery to add/remove .css to achieve this but as this is also within a Wordpress loop I get all images selected and not just the one relating to this button.

Are there any sudo elements to go up in the parent? And if not how could this be done? I was thinking;

to SELECT the image only above, but I have no idea how to write this, i tried using .prev() but had no luck.

Any Help greatly appreciated.

```
<!-- Services Inner Wrapper -->
<div class="services-archive-inner-wrapper">
    <!-- Flexed -->
    <div class="archive-flexed">
        <!-- Visual Content -->
        <div class="visual-content">
            <!-- Image Wrapper -->
            <a class="archive-image-wrapper" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                

                <!-- The Circular Image Is Here -->
                <!-- The Circular Image Is Here -->
                <!-- The Circular Image Is Here -->

                <?php>THE IMAGE IS HERE<?>

                <!-- The Circular Image Is Here -->
                <!-- The Circular Image Is Here -->
                <!-- The Circular Image Is Here -->


            </a>
            <!-- Archive Button Wrapper -->
            <div class="image-link-button-wrapper">
                <div class="coloured-link-detail">


                    <!-- The Circular Button Link Is Here -->
                    <!-- The Circular Button Link Is Here -->
                    <!-- The Circular Button Link Is Here -->

                        <a class="image-link-button" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><i class=" fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>

                    <!-- The Circular Button Link Is Here -->
                    <!-- The Circular Button Link Is Here -->
                    <!-- The Circular Button Link Is Here -->


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Archive Text Content -->
        <div class="archive-text-content">
            <h2 class="primary-border-left left-border-spacing article-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <!-- Archive Sub Title -->
            <h3 class="primary-border-left left-border-spacing article-sub-head"><?php the_field('job_title'); ?></h3>
            <!-- Archive Copy -->
            <div class="primary-border-left left-border-spacing">
                <?php echo first_section_copy_excerpt(); ?>
                <a class="archive-read-more" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">Read More &raquo;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.archive-image-wrapper:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.115);
}
.archive-image-wrapper:hover + .image-link-button-wrapper .image-link-button {
    background: purple;
    color: white;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.image-link-button').hover(function() {
    $('.archive-image-wrapper img').prev().css('transform', 'scale(1.115)');
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the javascript that you have tried?

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image-link-button').hover(function() {
        $('.archive-image-wrapper img').prev().css('transform', 'scale(1.115)');
    });
});
</script>